# Change foo@bar$ to foo@bar# for selected users

Tags: linux, prompt, rhel, sign

Does anyone know a way to display a # instead of a $ at a users prompt without giving them root access?

I have been trying to replace the "$" at the start of a users prompt's with a "#"
This is due to us revoking root access to these users, The users are fine with the limited access.
However some of the users are generating support calls because they no longer see the hash at the start of the prompt's, Thus thinking the system is broken. 
Our systems run RHEL 3,4,5 & 6.

I know this will be something in the `.bash_profile` however I cant find what.

Comment: You seriously gave root access to people that are complaining about the prompt appearance?

Comment: you can simply change the PS1 environment variable, eg. `PS1='[\u@\h \W]# '`

Comment: Gryphius! you are a legend mate!

Comment: I'd rather tell them what changed and that it is not an issue.

Comment: Oh trust me so would I, but apparently thats not how we do things

Answer (score 0):

make change in /etc/bashrc from :

[ "$PS1" = "\s-\v\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "

to

[ "$PS1" = "\s-\v\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]# "